# div translate from left to right and back

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

please is there a way i can make a div on clicking a button move from left to right and appear back to the left like infinite loop using pure react and css. Swipers "infinite-loop-with-slides-per-group" does this but i can't customize it to my needs

Answer (score 0):

you can use useState :

```
const [hasAnimation, setHasAnimation] = useState(false)
```

and on your button :

```
<button type="button" class=={hasAnimation ? "my_button my_animation" : "my_button"} onClick={() => setHasAnimation(prev => !prev)}
```

and you can style you button with my_button class and set animation in my_animation class. if user clicks on button the my_animation will add to.

Answer (score 0):

If I am thinking correctly you want a div that resembles the snake from the snake game. You can use CSS `translateX()` and start from 0vw(or the initial position) set a timeout to increase the number till 100vw(or more than it depending on your needs and the element size) and then back to 0vw(or less) once it crosses the screen in the right.

This is what I am saying https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ky8ecu?file=src/App.js

Comment: yes, i want to create a multple item slideshow exactly as it is on netflix. please can you give a sample just as it is on netflix

Comment: Okay so you want a slideshow that keeps looping, what you will need is to duplicate the items in the first fold at the end. Like you have images `[a, b, c, d]` and two images are visible at a time so you'll do `[a, b, c, d, a, b]` and when the client reaches `d`, it will create an illusion that he is seeing the start(whereas he is at the 5th item) and at this point you'll sneakily switch to the start.
Please refer this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KcdBOoK3Pfw